# How to create order Manually in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, cordova, woocommerce

i had develop a phonegap application with my woocommerce store.
now i want to create order manually.
So anyone can tell me when new order is created in woocommerce store how many data inserted in which tables in database. i mean data at the time of new order generation in which table and in which fashion are they stored. Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A order in WooCommerce is stored as as WordPress post with `post_type = 'shop_order'` in the table `wp_posts`.

Each order item in the order is stored in `wp_woocommerce_order_items`, with additional information about each order item line in the table `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta`.

To add a new order:

1. Insert a new order into the `wp_posts` table
2. Add the requested order lines into `wp_woocommerce_order_items`
3. For each of the order lines, add the order line details into `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta`.

Example data from a MySQL dump:

```
INSERT INTO wp_posts VALUES (38,1,'2014-06-09 10:02:00','2014-06-09 10:02:00','','Order &ndash; June 9, 2014 @ 10:02 AM','','publish','closed','closed','','order','','','2014-06-09 10:02:43','2014-06-09 10:02:43','',0,'http://example.com/?post_type=shop_order&#038;p=38',0,'shop_order','',0);

INSERT INTO wp_woocommerce_order_items VALUES (33,'My product','line_item',38);

INSERT INTO wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta VALUES (167,33,'_qty','1');
INSERT INTO wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta VALUES (168,33,'_tax_class','');
INSERT INTO wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta VALUES (169,33,'_product_id','20');
INSERT INTO wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta VALUES (170,33,'_variation_id','');
INSERT INTO wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta VALUES (171,33,'_line_subtotal','13');
INSERT INTO wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta VALUES (172,33,'_line_subtotal_tax','');
INSERT INTO wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta VALUES (173,33,'_line_total','13');
INSERT INTO wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta VALUES (174,33,'_line_tax','');
```

I would recommend that you try manually creating an order in the database with the settings you want the generated order to have, that way you see the relations and the various settings that you will need to set manually.

Comment: can you guys tell me by which file order data is inserted in database at the time order creation...

Comment: Do you mean in what PHP file in WordPress/WooCommerce the code for a regular, in-store order creation resides?

Comment: yes and tell me one thing that where is the tax of order stored in database

Comment: Check out the last row inserted into `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` - the `_line_tax` meta value. The easiest way to figure out exactly what rows and fields are involved, is manipulating orders/products through the regular WooCommerce interface while using a MySQL interface to see what changedd.

Answer (score 1):

I spent many hours on this code - so I want to share it.
 It creates a new order, with one product, adds shipment to the order with the flat rate of shipment, by the postcode of the customer.
 I use it to create subscription orders for my clients.

```
function create_order($user_id, $product_id)
{
    $order = wc_create_order();
    $order->set_created_via("subscription");
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $order->add_product($product, $quantity);
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
    $postcode = get_user_meta($user_id, 'shipping_postcode', true);
    $package = array('destination' => array('country' => 'IL', 'postcode' => $postcode));
    $zone = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zone_matching_package($package);
    $method = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_shipping_method( $zone->get_id() );
```

This was the hardest to find out. The get_shipping_method returns class name. The next line create instance of it.

```
$shipping = new $method;
```

Now get the price of the shipment:

```
$rate = new WC_Shipping_Rate();
$rate->id = 'flat_rate';
$rate->label = 'shipment';
$rate->cost = $shipping->cost;
$rate->calc_tax = 'per_order'; // Not sure about this one
// Adding it to the order
$order->add_shipping($rate);
$order->calculate_totals();

// assign the order to the current user
update_post_meta($order->get_id(), '_customer_user', $user_id);
// payment_complete
$order->payment_complete();`
```

Copy billing and shipment info

```
     foreach (array('billing_first_name',
 'billing_last_name',
 'billing_phone',
 'billing_address_1',
 'billing_address_2',
 'shipping_first_name',
 'shipping_last_name',
 'shipping_address_1',
 'shipping_address_2',
 'shipping_city',
 'shipping_postcode') as $key) {
 $values = get_user_meta($user_id, $key);
 update_post_meta($order_id, "_" . $key, $values[0]);
}
```